# How can we show that $n < 2^n$ for all natural numbers $n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, alternative-proof

I proved it using calculus or by drawing their graph but I was thinking if there is any simpler way to prove it. Please help me.

Proof by induction >
$P(n) : n < 2^n$ for all $n \in\mathbb{N}$

$P(1) : 1 < 2^1$, i.e.
$1 < 2,$ this is a true statement.

Now lets assume $P(m)$ is true i.e. $m < 2^m$ .

So $P(m + 1) : m + 1 < 2^{m + 1}.$

Now 
$m < 2 ^ m \Rightarrow 2m < 2^{m + 1} \\
\Rightarrow m+m < 2^{m+1}\\
\Rightarrow m+1 <= m+m < 2^{m+1}\\
\Rightarrow m+1 < 2^(m+1)$

Hence $P(m+1)$ is true. Thus $P(m)$ is true $\Rightarrow P(m+1)$ so by principle of mathematical induction $P(n)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$
So as I said I know the proof using induction hence I wanted to know any other way to prove it.

Comment: Try [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Comment: $\mathbb{N} := \{0,1,2,...\}$ in my convention. $n=0$ gives $0<1$. Suppose $n<2^n$ then $n+1<2^n+1$ and since $1<2$ we find ...

Comment: $2^n$ is the cardinality of the power set of a set of $n$ elements; the power set includes $n$ singletons and other set(s), including the empty set

Comment: A graph in calculus is not sufficient since you want to prove it for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Plus you cannot use calculus on $\mathbb{R}^d$. I guess you mean a mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I also know the induction proof . Please tell me any other proof

Comment: Please edit your post to include your proof by induction...that's pretty much the easiest way to proceed.

Comment: I edited my comment Mr lulu , now will you please answer my query.

Comment: You first posting asked for a simpler way than calculus.  The simplest way is induction.  Now you say you want another.  Why?  What actually *is* your question?  In essence: the *reason* this is true is that multiplying a "full result" by $2$ is adding the full result to itself which is more than adding just $1$.  So multiplying $2$ by itself $n$ times to get $2^n$ will always be a larger result than adding $1$ to itself $n$ times to get $n$.  I don't think any proof can get simpler in concept than that.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Interesting... It's hard to say if I'd call that proof "simpler".  It could be if you accept that $2^n$ is the cardinality of the power set but if you have to learn the concept and prove that it certainly wouldn't be.  ... So your proof could be argued to be simpler and more complicated... neat.

Comment: @fleablood:  each of the $n$ elements is in or not in an element of the power set, so there are $2^n$ power set elements

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I know but I don't consider that "simpler" (I didn't say it was *hard*; just that it's not as "simple")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you ask for proof other than that by induction, consider $$2^n=(1+1)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\dots+\binom{n}{n} > \binom{n}{1}=n$$ as an application of [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: Excellent proof!

Answer (score 8):

$2^n$ is the cardinality of the power set of a set of $n$ elements.

The power set includes $n$ singletons and the empty set.

Comment: fancy answer !!

Answer (score 2):

Summary of comments that should have been answers:

- If $n<2^n$ with $n\ge1$ then $n+1\le 2n<2^{n+1}$, so we can induct from $n=1$ onward, and only need to check the base steps $n=0$ and $n=1$;
- A hypothetical function $f$ mapping elements of $\{1,\,\cdots,\,n\}$ to subsets thereof can't satisfy $f(k)=\{m|m\notin f(m)\}$ (as this would lead to the contradiction $k\in f(k)\iff k\notin f(k)$), [so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) there are too many subsets to pair with elements.

A recent comment reveals the first approach is known & not desired.

Answer (score 2):

*A combinatorial proof:*

Note that $$2^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\,\binom{n}{i}=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\cdots,$$ that $$n=\binom{n}{1}$$ and that all terms are of the sum are positive.

Then the result follows immediately.

Answer (score 2):

The [Bernoulli inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) says that, if $t>-1$ and $n$ is any nonnegative integer, then
$$(1+t)^n\ge 1+nt$$
this inequality can be proved by induction (and is more useful than just proving that $n<2^n$). It is true for $n=0$, because both sides have the value $1$.
Suppose $(1+t)^n\ge 1+nt$, then
$$\begin{align}(1+t)^{n+1}&=(1+t)^n(1+t)\\&\ge(1+nt)(1+t)\\&=1+(n+1)t+nt^2\\&\ge1+(n+1)t\end{align}$$
We used $t>-1$ to write the first inequality; the last one holds because $nt^2\ge0$.
Now apply the inequality to the case $t=1$:
$$2^n=(1+1)^n\ge1+n1=1+n>n$$

Answer (score 1):

We can prove this by induction on $n$:

Base case: clearly $n < 2^n$ is true for $n=1$ because $1 < 2^1 = 2$. This proves the base case.

Inductive step: Assume $n < 2^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This implies $2n < 2 \cdot 2^n = 2^{n+1}$. Moreover, $n+1 \leq 2n$ for all $n \geq 1$. So $n+1 \leq 2n < 2^{n+1} \implies n+1 < 2^{n+1}$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Induction:

If $k < 2^k$ (which is true for the first few natural $k$) and $k \ge 1$ (which is true for all $k$) then:

$k +1 \le k + k < 2^k + 2^k = 2^{k+1}$ and thus for any natural number this is true for it will be true for the next and there will be none where it isn't true.

.....

In essence, multiplying a number, $n$ by $b \ge 2$ (which is adding $n \ge 1$ to $n$ a positive number of times) results in a larger value then adding $1$ to the number (because adding $1$ is less [or equal] to adding $n$ and the number times done in multiplying are more than the just once of adding $1$).  So $n$ is the result of adding $1$, $n$ times, while $2^n$ is the result of multiplying $2$ $n$ times.  Each multiplication by $2$ must result in a larger value than just adding $1$ would.

Answer (score 1):

Let f(X)=X-$2^X$ for all X $\ge$1
$$f'(X)=1-2^X.ln(2)\lt 0$$
f(X) is decreasing function for all X$\ge$1.
Hence $f(X)\lt f(1)=-1\lt 0$
Hence $X\lt 2^X\,\,\,\,\forall X\ge 1$

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(n) = 2^n - n$ is monotone increasing on $(0,\infty)$ and since $f(1) > 0, f(n)> 0\forall\; n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Answer (score 0):

By Cantor, for every set $X$, $|\mathcal P(X)| > |X|$. When $X$ is a set with $n$ elements, it follows that $2^n > n$.